# Rails comment scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a model Comment inside a Post model. I set scoping (fresh or hot) to my posts and it's working, but when I'm trying to set scopes to comments nothing happens. Please help.
**Comment.rb:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_votable

 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :user

 scope :recent, -> {order('created_at DESC')}
 scope :hot,    -> {order('cached_votes_up DESC')}
end
```

**Comments_controller.rb:**

```
def recent
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 @comments = @post.comments.recent
 render 'posts/show'
end

def hot
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 @comments = @post.comments.hot
 render 'posts/show'
end
```

**show.html.erb (for a post):**

```
<p><%= link_to 'show fresh', recent_post_comments_path(@post) %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'show most liked', hot_post_comments_path(@post) %></p>

<div>
    <% @post.comments.each do |c|%>
        <p><%=  c.content %></p>
        ...
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: When redirecting, you are loosing all your instance variables, as new action will be handled by a new controller instance.

Comment: By using render - `render "posts/show"`

Comment: I changed it to render 'posts/show', page seems to be loaded correctry, but scoping is still not working

Comment: Can you edit your post to reflect whatever changes you've made? Just want to make sure we're all on the same page here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a solution and it's pretty easy. All I needed was to add

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comments = @post.comments.hot
```

to posts#show

Answer (score 0):

In your `show.html.erb`, you're not using your `@comments` instance variable. You're using `@post.comments`.

What you need to do is use `@comments` in your view, and in your controller, to assign `@comments` to `@post.comments.hot` (yes, you can apply scopes to an association).

Comment: I can't undestand how to use `@comments` in `show.html.erb`. I changed code in controller to this `@comments = @post.comments.recent`

Comment: That seems correct – does it not work (but `@post` works)?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. I have no idea what's wrong. I had no problems with scoping the Post model

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't specific error. what's the error you're encountering?

Comment: I dont get any errors! I press the link, page reloads, adress bar says '/posts/17/comments/recent', but nothing happens to comments